# Eclipse automatically run maven goals

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

In my Eclipse/Maven project, how can I call the buildHelper goals `add-test-source`, `add-test-resource` and `add-resource`?

This is my approach:

`pom.xml`:

```
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.0.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                                        <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
                                        <goal>add-resource</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-compile-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.0.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>compile</goal>
                                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute>
                                        <runOnIncremental>true</runOnIncremental>
                                    </execute>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

`lifecycle-mapping-metadata.xml` (from Eclipse config):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
      <pluginExecutions>

      </pluginExecutions>
    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
```

To test, I put an empty file into a test resources directory, change a source file, save and check if the empty file is in the corresponding `target/` directory afterwards. **It isn't**.

When I manually run `compile test-compile`, the test file is getting copied.